# systemd-journal-remote strange behavior

Tags: linux, systemd, journald

I have `systemd` v253 running on Fedora 38.
My `journal-remote.conf` file is:

```
[Remote]
Seal=True
SplitMode=host
# ....
MaxUse=5G
KeepFree=10G
MaxFiles=500
```

and my full `journald.conf` is:

```
[Journal]
Storage=persistent
Compress=yes
Seal=yes
SplitMode=none
SyncIntervalSec=5m
RateLimitIntervalSec=0
#RateLimitIntervalSec=30s
#RateLimitBurst=10000
SystemMaxUse=200G
SystemKeepFree=10G
SystemMaxFileSize=1G
SystemMaxFiles=200
RuntimeMaxUse=1G
RuntimeKeepFree=1G
#RuntimeMaxFileSize=
#RuntimeMaxFiles=100
MaxRetentionSec=1month
#MaxFileSec=1month
ForwardToSyslog=no
ForwardToKMsg=no
ForwardToConsole=yes
ForwardToWall=yes
#TTYPath=/dev/console
#MaxLevelStore=debug
#MaxLevelSyslog=debug
#MaxLevelKMsg=notice
MaxLevelConsole=alert
MaxLevelWall=emerg
#LineMax=48K
ReadKMsg=yes
Audit=yes
```

Currently I can observe strange behavior of `systemd-journal-remote` which I cannot explain. It has some subproblems in it:

1. `systemd-journal-remote` tries to read `/var/log/journal/ID_JOURNAL/fss` file from time to time. As it does not have sufficient privilege's so I get errors in journald log. I found a bug description here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1262743 but I am not sure if I should add `systemd-journal-upload` user to `systemd-journal`. Why whould `systemd-journal-remote` need that file and is it safe to unite its user and journald group?
2. I am completely confused by the way `systemd-journal-remote` processes rotation. With config file above my 1Tb partition is full of log files delivered from remote servers and it seems that rotation does not occur at all. I know that there was a bug in 252 (https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/5242) and it has been corrected in 253, but still I get no rotation. Is there anything else I should know about rotation in `systemd-journal-remote`?
3. If I use a parameter `MaxFileSize` set to, say, 10G or even 1G, I get a list of errors like that:

> Oct 22 07:47:16 node2 systemd-journal-remote[70263]: Failed to get writer for source 172.16.12.12: Argument list too long

and

> Oct 22 07:47:22 node2 systemd-journal-remote[70263]: Failed to open /var/log/journal/2323332558c634950b625661a256dc345/fss: Permission denied

But when I remove that parameter - everything works. I checked *.service* file and I have no idea why and what argument list is long here.

4. The majority of my log files in `journal` directory do have a size of 128Mb and I have no idea why it is so, although I set up `SystemMaxFileSize=1G` - it is simply ignored. I found some explanation here: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/25124, checked myself I got the same result: 128Mb. Does it mean that `SystemMaxFileSize` plays no role in config file?

And the last small request: I get many logs from remote machines and the amount is as high as 2 Gb/min. What would you tune in default setup of journald/remote journald to eliminate possible problems with its performance? Is it better to switch to `rsyslog` or it is OK to keep up with `systemd-journald`?

Thank you!

Comment: Small note: I was able to solve the problem with overflowing with logs by switching to single file and making restrictions on file size and their quantity. It seems that there is some sort of a bug in systemd that blocks log rotation in multiple files for journald-remote.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to a single storage log file (*Split=none*) and setup restrictions for size and files quantity (*System** settings in *journald.conf*). That worked for me.